# Sources of phonegap + jquery mobile sample

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

Does anyone know a good example of using **Phonegap** and **jQuery Mobile** together? It shouldn't be trivial example from the docs - real app, that uses input validation, stores data, calls web-services, uses camera, maps and so on. I try to find smth, but most of the Phonegap+JQuery examples are too simple and have no cases of using Device API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is to big, you need to specify a bit more what you want to learn.

Check this out:
http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/

But asking a question like this, you need to provide some more info.  Searching on google is not really a question is it? ;-)

Take care.

Comment: This should be a comment. Don't you think ?

Answer (score 3):

Refer this url , it should help

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/10/Example-of-serverbased-login-with-PhoneGap